# Kendo Date Picker - Passing Incorrect Date Format to Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I am using KendoDatePicker, I use this all over my application. However, I am suddenly having an issue with it passing dates in wrong format.

```
  @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
            .Name("ToDate")
            .Min(DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1)) //Set the min date of the DatePicker.
            .Max(DateTime.Today) //Set the min date of the DatePicker.
            .Value(DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")) // I have also just set DateTime.Today, without formating as string
```

)

I use the following JS function to retrieve the date from the date picker:

```
function getDatePickerValue() {
 var toDate= $("#ToDate").val();
   return {
            transactionToDate: toDate
        }
}
```

I then pass this value to my controller, which takes the date and filters a grid.  This is what is being passed (as seen in my Network debugger):
**transactionToDate:"01/04/2016"**

This is my controller method

```
 public JsonResult GetCustomerElectronicTransactions([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, DateTime? transactionToDate){}
```

My controller is recognizing the date as **MM/DD/YYYY**, but it actually being passed as **DD/MM/YYYY**, so what is happening is that my Months and Days are being switch when passed.

Does anyone have any suggestion? I don't understand why this is suddenly giving me an issue, I've used this exact setup in other controller/views without an issue.

Thoughts?

Comment: maybe culture is not properly set or got messed up somewhere. you might try adding this line to web.confog `<globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US" />`

Answer (score 1):

The problems was to do with the way I was getting the value of the datepicker in JS.
I changed :

```
function getDatePickerValue() {
 var toDate= $("#ToDate").val();
   return {
            transactionToDate: toDate
        }
}
```

To:

```
function getDatePickerValue() {
 var toDate= $("#ToDate").data("kendoDatePicker").value();
   return {
            transactionToDate: toDate
        }
}
```